# Using variables in Given-When-Then Gherkin/Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock, gherkin

I want to use a date variable in my Given -When- Then,  I am doing following but it gives error.

```
 where: "For #sql_date"
    variable << condition1
```

However, In my Spock reports it gives me output like this

Where:
For #Error:sql_date

How do I use sql_date variable in where.

Comment: where have you created sql_date? It needs to be defined somewhere isn't it ?

Comment: Share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a two-line snippet without context which cannot be executed. BTW, variable names can only be references in that `#myVar` way from unrolled feature method titles when declared in the `when:` block. AFAIK they cannot be used from given/when/then/... comments.

Comment: sql_date is defined as @Shared def sql_date

Comment: OK, I think I know what is going on- the value of the date was not being calculated , hence it was not getting displayed